# VB.net Null error

Tags: vb.net, null, argumentnullexception

Im having an issue trying to handle a  *ArgumentNullExeption occured*

*value cant be Null*

*paramiter name item*

So far ive tried the following

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim ArgumentNullException As New Boolean
        If (ListBox2.Items.Add(ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString = "")) Then
           MessageBox.Show("please pick from list", "error")
        End If
        ListBox1.Items.Remove(ListBox1.SelectedItem)

 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim ArgumentNullException As New Boolean
        If (ListBox2.Items.Add(ListBox1.SelectedItem Is Nothing)) Then
           MessageBox.Show("please pick from list", "error")
        End If
        ListBox1.Items.Remove(ListBox1.SelectedItem)


 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim ArgumentNullException As New BooleanListBox2
        ListBox2.Items.Add(ListBox1.SelectedItem)
        If (ListBox1.SelectedItem) = ""
           MessageBox.Show("please pick from list", "error")
        ListBox1.Items.Remove(ListBox1.SelectedItem)
```

And error still comes up can anyone assist please

Updated:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
            ListBox2.Items.Add(ListBox1.SelectedItem)
            If IsNothing (ListBox1.SelectedItem)
               MessageBox.Show("please pick from list", "error")
            ListBox1.Items.Remove(ListBox1.SelectedItem)
```

Gives error still

Comment: It is better for you to paste the whole related code, such as initialization of List variable.

Comment: What on earth is this: `If (ListBox2.Items.Add(ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString = "")) Then`??

Comment: Noob trial and error

Comment: i read a post that didnt work so then just tried differnt combos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Question is pretty unclear, but I'll give it a try.

---

When your application has `Listboxes` and uses the `.SelectedItem` attribute you should always use Try/Catch or even better check if the user has selected and item:

```
If IsNothing(ListBox1.SelectedItem) Then Exit Sub
```

You could also use

```
If ListBox1.SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
```

You could also use If/Else, but putting the statement in the very first Line of the Code makes it more readable in my opinion.

Using this code will make your button do nothing, when there are no selected items.
Otherwise you can use multiline-If to put a `MsgBox("Please pick an Item")`, to warn the user:

```
If IsNothing(ListBox1.SelectedItem) Then
    MsgBox("Please pick an Item first.")
    Exit Sub
End If
// Your Code after that
```

---

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  // Leave the Sub and Message the User, when there is no SelectedItem
  If IsNothing(ListBox1.SelectedItem) Then
      MsgBox("Please pick an Item first.")
      Exit Sub
  End If
  // Code will only reach here, when there is a SelectedItem
  ListBox2.Items.Add(ListBox1.SelectedItem)
  ListBox1.Items.Remove(ListBox1.SelectedItem)
End sub
```

Comment: My aim is to have the message box appear if the user just presses the button without selecting an item

Comment: Thanks was missing the *end sub*

Comment: Glad I could help. Always remember: Everything you open, needs to be closed somewhere: If / End if, While/EndWhile, Function/End Function, Sub/End Sub, Select Case/End Select, (...)